# Anchor links in HTML file don't work in iframe after iOS fix

Tags: ios, css, iframe, hyperlink, overflow

Ok, so I am working on a javascript application.  One feature is a help page for the application.  The way I am trying to do it is to have a button that opens the help page - .html - in an iframe contained within a container div.

This works just fine, but I run into the well-known issue of iframes not scrolling in iOS(i.e. on iPads and iPhones).

There is a common fix for this, which involves setting overflow rules in the css for the container div.

So the initial CSS is something like:

```
#iframeContainer {
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    width: 750px;
}

#iframeContainer iframe {
{
    width:100%;
    height: 600px;
}
```

and the css with the iOS fix is something like:

```
#iframeContainer {
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    width: 750px;
    height: 600px;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    overflow: scroll;
}

#iframeContainer iframe {
{
    width:100%;
    height: 12000px;
}
```

The overflow rules are added to the css for the container, but in order to work, you have to set a height on the container.  You also have to adjust the height of the iframe itself.  If I leave it at its initial 600px, it never overflows the container div and there is no scrolling.  If I don't set any height at all on the iframe, it hardly shows anything at all.  So I have to set the iframe's height to contain all of the contents of the HTML file, which comes to 12000px.

All of this works, and the scrolling issue on iOS is fixed.  But here's where I run into the issue in question.

The HTML page being loaded into the iframe has within it a bunch of anchor links that link to other places on the same page.  After applying the iOS fix, those anchor links no longer work at all.  Nothing happens when they're clicked.

I am reasonably sure that the reason is because when I set the iframe's height to 12000px, the HTML page behaves as though it is all displayed on one page, in which event, nothing happening is the appropriate behavior for anchor links.

So I think understand what is going on, and I'm just wondering if anyone has any ideas on how to make the anchor links work while keeping the iOS fix in tact.  If I decrease the iframe's height to make the anchor links work, then less and less of the HTML page will show up within the iframe.  If I remove the iOS fix all together, the anchor links will work but the scrolling won't work on iOS.

Open to anything.  For the time being, I've abandoned the idea and the 'Help' button just opens the HTML page in a new tab/window.